# Recursively reversing a linked list in Java

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have two classes, `ListNode` and `MyList`.

ListNode:

```
public class ListNode {
    private String str;
    private ListNode next;
    public ListNode(String str) {
        this.str = str;
        next = null;
    }
    public String getString() {
        return str;
    }
    public ListNode getNext() {
        return next;
    }
    public void setNext(ListNode next) {
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

MyList

```
public MyList RecReverse() { //my attempt at the recursive method
    if (head.getNext() == null) {
        return this;
    }
    MyList remainder = new MyList();
    remainder.head = head.getNext(); //start rest of list at the 2nd thing
    ListNode temp = new ListNode(head.getString()); //get the first thing in list
    temp.setNext(null); //set to null to indicate end of list

    remainder.RecReverse(); //reverse the remaining things in the list
    remainder.head.setNext(temp); //then add it to the end of the reversed list

    return remainder;



}
```

So as you can see the `MyList` class has a `ListNode` variable which we need to use. It is required that the `RecReverse` method take no arguments and return a `MyList` object. The method must also use the function `` Rev(L) = Rev(L`).x ``, where `` L` `` is the remainder of the list and `x` is the first thing in the list.

Currently when I reverse the list and print it it only prints the following:

> two
>
> one

in the console

Comment: Is this homework?  Trace through your program, to figure out why you're narrowly avoiding an endless loop.  There should be a number of algorithms available online that show how to do this.  You don't need to explicitly call `temp.setNext(null);`, as the constructor sets it by default.  Is there another constructor that also takes the `next` node?

Comment: Is your objective to reverse a linked list or you want to reverse a linked list only recursively ?

Comment: Yeah, it's homework. I couldn't find anything online that did this specifically without arguments in the recursive method, so that's why I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public MyList RecReverse() { //my attempt at the recursive method
    if (head.getNext() == null) {
        return this;
    }

    MyList remainder = new MyList();
    remainder.head = head.getNext(); // New list has rest of this list (after head)
    ListNode temp = new ListNode(head.getString()); // save the first thing in list

    remainder = remainder.RecReverse(); //reverse the things in the new 2nd part list

    remainder.end().setNext(temp); // put old head on the end

    return remainder;

}

private ListNode end() {
    ListNode curr = head;
    while (curr.getNext() != null) {
        curr = curr.getNext();
    }
    return curr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you somehow managed to keep the tail of the original list, you would get the correct result. The problem is that in each recursive call you assemble the correct list but return the list containing 2 elements. See Lee Meador's answer for the correct solution; you could optimize it if you kept the end in the list structure.

Comment: Yep, just when I thought I had recursion all figured out. Thanks for explaining.